# grouping in dailysales report in SQL Server giving wrong output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to generate a daily sale report for my restaurant.
Restaurant will open at 4:00 AM and close at 3:59 AM next day.

Query for the daily sale is like below..

```
select DATENAME(month, sa.StartDate) 'Month Name', 
datename(dw,sa.StartDate)'Day',
Convert(Varchar,CONVERT(date,sa.StartDate),103) 'Date',
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), SUM(sa.OrigionalSubTotal) / 100.0) 'Gross Sales' 
from Store st,
Sale sa
where 
 st.StoreID = sa.StoreID and st.StoreID =xxxxxx
 and sa.StartDate >= '2015-05-01 04:00:01' and sa.StartDate <= '2015-05-02 03:59:00' 
group by st.StoreName,CONVERT(date, sa.StartDate),
datename(dw,sa.StartDate),
DATENAME(month, sa.StartDate)
order by Convert(Varchar,CONVERT(date,sa.StartDate),103)
```

Here I am taking sale from 1st May sales. That is 1st May morning 4:00AM to 2nd May Morning 3:59 AM, because of grouping the query with day name and date it will give two rows if any sale is happened after 12:00AM

Example:

```
May  Friday    01/05/2015      500
May  Saturday  02/05/2015      250
```

actually both sale should come in Friday ,because of the day and date coming in the query it will split into two.

The actual output should be

```
May Friday 01/05/2015   750
```

I can't use min() function on the start date to get the day name and date because the report can be run for more than one day.

Is there any way to achieve the same with a query or i should use some stored procedure and intermediate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should shift the date by 4hours:

- 4:00AM will become 00:00AM
- 3:59AM will become 11:59PM.

  ```
  select DATENAME(month, dateadd(hour, -4, sa.StartDate)) 'Month Name', 
      datename(dw, dateadd(hour, -4, sa.StartDate))'Day',
      Convert(Varchar,CONVERT(date, dateadd(hour, -4, sa.StartDate)),103) 'Date',
      CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), SUM(sa.OrigionalSubTotal) / 100.0) 'Gross Sales' 
  from Store st
  inner join Sale sa on st.StoreID = sa.StoreID
  where st.StoreID =xxxxxx
  and sa.StartDate >= '2015-05-01 04:00:01' and sa.StartDate <= '2015-05-02 03:59:00' 
  group by st.StoreName, CONVERT(dateadd(hour, -4, sa.StartDate)),        datename(dw,sa.StartDate),
  DATENAME(month, dateadd(hour, -4, sa.StartDate))
  order by Convert(Varchar,CONVERT(date, dateadd(hour, -4, sa.StartDate)),103)
  ```

You should also use the ANSI syntax for join. `From A, B Where` is the old syntax.

Comment: Thanks..its solved...i solved it by using case statement..but this one is more good..will use this..thanks a lot..

Comment: if the shift is btwn 9:00PM to next day 9:00PM hw to achieve is it fine if i do -9 insteda of -4?

Comment: Yes, I shift it by 4h because 04:00 needs to become 00:00. If it starts at 09:00, use -9 instead of -4.